# Showing a hierarchy using ng-repeat in a table

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display some hierarchical data stored in a json object in an html table. I tried with the following code from jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vGUsu/

```
//HTML

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<my-table rows='rows'></my-table>
</div>  


//javascript
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.directive('myTable', function () {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = '<table>';
        angular.forEach(scope[attrs.rows], function (row, index) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + row.name + '</td></tr>';
            if ('subrows' in row) {
                angular.forEach(row.subrows, function (subrow, index) {
                    html += '<tr><td>' + subrow.name + '</td></tr>';
                })
            }
        })
        html += '</table>';
        element.replaceWith(html)
    }
}
});

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.rows = [
    { name: 'a', subrows: [{ name: 'a.1' }, { name: 'a.2' }] },
    { name: 'b', subrows: [{ name: 'b.1',subrows: [{ name: 'b.1.1' }, { name: 'b.1.2' }] }, { name: 'b.2' }] }
];
}
```

I get the output as:

```
 a
 a.1
 a.2
 b
 b.1
 b.2
```

But I need to get:

```
 a
 a.1
 a.2
 b
 b.1
 b.1.1
 b.1.2
 b.2
```

I should be able to traverse as many levels as possible and show them in a table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a data structure in the shape of a tree and you could solve it with a recursive function to explore your tree.

I wrote the following piece of code that should get you on your way. I'm pretty sure it can be done a bit more elegantly by using additional variables.

JS: (did not alter your controller)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myTable', function () {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var text = '';

            function tableRec(array) {
              if(array.length === 0) {
                return text;
              } else {
                var obj = array.shift();

               text += '<tr><td>' + obj.name + '</td></tr>';
               //if there are subrows we go deeper into the recursion
                if(obj.subrows) {
                  tableRec(obj.subrows);
                }  

                tableRec(array);
              }
            }

            tableRec(scope[attrs.rows]);

            var html = '<table>' + text + '</table>';

            element.replaceWith(html)
        }
      }
   });
```

HTML: (unaltered)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <my-table rows='rows'></my-table>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
a
a.1
a.2
b
b.1
b.1.1
b.1.2
b.2
```

You can also find my plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jilN3VMBKWUubWHmav3c?p=preview).

Comment: Nice idea, but it's a kind work around, better we should have some real flavor of Angular. Appreciate skubski, if you share more related to angularJS.

Comment: @ChetanSharma Indeed it could be achieved in a more Angular way but the basic idea would remain the same. I'm sure there are some projects, like: [angular-recursive](https://github.com/marklagendijk/angular-recursion) with an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JAIyolmqPqO9KsynSiZp?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.